# $injector:modulerr after r.js optimization, but not before

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, r.js

I'm using `require.js` with `r.js` to optimize.  Pre-optimization, I have:

```
// MainCtrl.js
define(function () {
    return ["$scope", function ($scope) { console.log($scope); }];
});

// main.js
require.config({                                                                
    shim: {                                                                     
        angular: {                                                              
            exports: "angular",                                                 
        },                                                                      
    },                                                                          
    paths: {                                                                    
        angular: "lib/angular.min",                                             
    },                                                                          
});
require(["angular", "MainCtrl"], function (ng, MainCtrl) {
    console.log(ng);
    var app = ng.module("myapp", []);
    app.controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl);
});
```

My HTML is very simple; it just has `ng-app=myapp` in `<html>` and `ng-controller=MainCtrl` on `<body>`.

When I run the app like this, everything seems to work.  I get the `console.log` for `ng` which appears to be the `angular` object.  Then, I get the `console.log` for `$scope` from `MainCtrl`.  No problems.

After running `r.js` and using the minified `main.js`, I get errors and things no longer work.  I run `r.js -o build.js`.

```
// build.js
({                                                                              
    appDir: "public",                                                           
    baseUrl: "js",                                                              
    dir: "dist",                                                                
    fileExlusionRegExp: /^(r|build\.js)$/,                                      
    optimize: "uglify2",                                                        
    optimizeCss: "standard",                                                    
    modules: [{                                                                 
        name: "main"                                                            
    }],                                                                         
    paths: {                                                                    
        angular: "lib/angular.min",                                             
    },                                                                          
})
```

*Now* when I visit `index.html` I get errors:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   undefined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'module' of undefined

1. Seems to indicate that angular is not loading properly or something.  It can't inject something to `myapp`, but it has no dependencies.  Not `ngRoute` or anything
2. `ng` is now undefined even though it was correctly `angular` before.  This also causes the second error
3. The `console.log` in `MainCtrl` is not called.  Not a huge surprise since there is an error on the previous line.  *However*, if I change `ng` to `angular` the `undefined` error does not occur and `app.controller` gets called, but the `console.log` from `MainCtrl` is *still* not called.

My only guess is that angular is being minified twice (I'm already using angular.min.js and then `r.js` minifies it again).  Can I do anything to fix this issue?

Comment: Try setting `optimize` to `none` to see what is the order in which the apps are placed in the final build. That might give a hint.

Comment: @musically_ut okay, I've done that.  All of `angular.min.js` comes first followed by `define("angular",function(){})` -- that seems to be wrong.  However, if I move the `require...angular.module` block to the *top* of the file (before `angular.min` code) everything works!  This doesn't make sense to me since typically the angular code would come first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [`shim` documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim), it is suggests:

> You should use the mainConfigFile build option to specify the file where to find the shim config. Otherwise the optimizer will not know of the shim config. The other option is to duplicate the shim config in the build profile.

This is probably causing `angular`'s shim to be absent from the built file.

Comment: Thanks, this makes the problematic `define("angular"` work correctly now.  Everything seems to be working as it should be.  I assumed that the shims would still work, but I understand now why that would not be the case.