# AngularJs $injector:modulerr after RequireJS r.js optimization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, r.js

The AngularJS-RequireJS app im building is throwing **Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e** error after r.js optimization . The problem didnt exist before  . I followed a similar question at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866868/injectormodulerr-after-r-js-optimization-but-not-) and added **mainConfigFile** to the build file , but still the problem persists . Here are the codes the respective files

**build.js**

```
({
    mainConfigFile:'js/main.js',
    appDir: "./",
    baseUrl: "js",
    dir: "/home/karthic/optimized-test",
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main"
        }
    ]
})
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: './js',
    paths: {
        angular: 'libs/angular-1.2.9',
        angularRoute: 'libs/angular-route-1.2.9'
    },
    shim: {
        'angularRoute': {
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'angularRoute'
        },
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        }
    }

});

require(['angular', 'controller', 'ang_when_routes', 'angularRoute'], function(angular, controller, angWhenRoutes, angularRoute) {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });

    angWhenRoutes.initRoutes(app);
    controller.controllerInit(app);

});
```

**controller.js**

```
define(function() {
     function controllerInit(app) {
         console.log('inside func cont');
         app.controller('mapApp', function($scope, $http, $location) {
             console.log('inside mapp,testing r.js optimizer');
         });
     }
     return {
         controllerInit: controllerInit
     }
 });
```

**ang_when_routes.js**

```
define(function() {
    function initRoutes(app) {
        app.config(
            function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
                $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
                $routeProvider.
                when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'index_content.html',
                    controller: 'mapApp'
                })

            });
    }
    return {
        initRoutes: initRoutes
    }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Optimizer error</title>
        <script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**index_content.html**

```
<p>Testing the r optimizer</p>
```

It'll be really helpful for me if the error can be fixed

Comment: I would say that it is really clear what is happening: your optimization is minimazing all the variable names. Here you can see how to avoid it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21110382/1679310. Also check the [Dependency annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) doc

Comment: You aren't declaring your controller or config correctly to work after minification. Read the docs

Comment: @RadimKöhler : Thanks a lot Sir !!! That works ....Again, thanks a lot , that was really important to me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer as suggested by @radimKohler in the first comment . To avoid issues with angularJS during minification **Inline array Annotation** has to be used as referred in the [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)  . Here is the modified code after the change

**controller.js**

```
define( function () {
     function controllerInit(app) {
         console.log('inside func cont');
         app.controller('mapApp',['$scope','$http','$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
             console.log('inside mapp,testing r.js optimizer');

         }]);

     }
     return {
         controllerInit: controllerInit
     }

 });
```

**ang_when_routes.js**

```
define(function(){
    function initRoutes(app){
        app.config(['$routeProvider','$httpProvider',
            function($routeProvider,$httpProvider){
                $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
                $routeProvider.
                    when('/',{
                        templateUrl:'index_content.html',
                        controller:'mapApp'
                    })

            }]);    

    }
    return {
        initRoutes:initRoutes
    }
});
```